# Как при нажатии кнопки поменять значение InlineKeyboardButton?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

При нажатии на кнопку, нужно из массива `а` вывести на кнопки остальные 5 значений или вернуть
Одни ошибку ловлю...

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['list'])
def all_commands(message):

    a = [ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8','9','10']
    key = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    one = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=a[0] ,callback_data='hex-dec' )
    two = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=a[1] ,callback_data='bin-dec' )
    three = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=a[2] ,callback_data='oct-dec' )
    four = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=a[3] ,callback_data= 'str-int')
    five = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=a[4] ,callback_data= 'bin-hex')
    nex = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Next = >', callback_data='next')
    prev = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='< = Prev', callback_data='prev')
    none = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='        ', callback_data='none')

    key.row(one, two, three, four, five)
    key.row(prev, none, nex)

    bot.send_message(chat_id='@qwerzxcva', text='This is what I can do:\n...', reply_markup=key)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def calling(message):
    if call.data == 'next': 
       pass                   #что и как правильно написать?
    if call.data == 'prev':
       pass                   #что и как правильно написать?


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вот вам пример собранный на коленке:

```
a = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
b = ['hex-dec', 'bin-dec', 'oct-dec', 'str-int', 'bin-hex', '6-hex', '7-hex', '8-hex', '9-hex', '10-hex']


def keyboard(c):
    if c == 1:
        key = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        buttons = []
        for i in range(6, len(a)):
            buttons.append(
                types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=str(a[i]), callback_data=str(b[i])))

        nex = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Next = >', callback_data='next')
        prev = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='< = Prev', callback_data='prev')
        key.add(*buttons)
        key.add(prev, nex)
        return key
    else:
        key = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        buttons = []
        for i in range(0, 5):
            buttons.append(
                types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=str(a[i]), callback_data=str(b[i])))

        nex = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Next = >', callback_data='next')
        prev = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='< = Prev', callback_data='prev')
        key.add(*buttons)
        key.add(prev, nex)
        return key


@bot.message_handler(commands=['list'])
def all_commands(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'This is what I can do:\n...', reply_markup=keyboard(0))


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def calling(call):
    print(call.data)

    if call.data == 'next':
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text='Выберите:',
                              reply_markup=keyboard(1))
    if call.data == 'prev':
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text='Выберите:',
                              reply_markup=keyboard(0))
```

здесь можно заменить два списка на словарь и вытягивать k,v; избавиться от `if c == 1`, дерзайте!

Comment: Не работает...
Я конечно не уверен, но reply_markup не может принимать функцию

Comment: Этот код был написан специально для ответа и проверен не раз. Показывайте ошибки. Может принимать функцию

Comment: у вас получилось?

Comment: @dviolet,  да, спасибо, все получилось, я просто когда корректировал код, не правильно написал аргумент